# Prefix every file in subdirectories with the folder name

Tags: bash, powershell, file, batch-file, rename

Preferably using bash or PowerShell, I would like to prefix every file in subdirectories of a directory with their respective folder name.

Each folder has a series of PDF forms with generic names. The folders possess the names of the individuals who are to sign the forms, so are to be renamed accordingly.

This PowerShell snippet seems similar to what I'll need,

```
dir | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + "_" + $_.Name}
```

--but I couldn't figure out how to make it apply to all subdirectories.

Thank you deeply in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Get-ChildItem` (alias `dir`) and specify parameters `Recurse` and `File` at least, so your code will traverse subdirectories and rename files only (not also folder objects)

```
$rootFolder = 'D:\Test'   # the folder where the subfolders storing the PDF files are
(Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Filter '*.pdf' -File -Recurse) | Rename-Item -NewName {
    '{0}_{1}' -f $_.Directory.Name, $_.Name
}
```

If you run the above several times, then each time the pdf files get their name prefixed with the directory name, so you'll end up with files like `foo_foo_foo_file1.pdf`.

To prevent that from happening, you can add a `Where-Object` clause like:

```
$rootFolder = 'D:\Test'
(Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Filter '*.pdf' -File -Recurse) | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch "^$($_.Directory.Name)_" } |
    Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}_{1}' -f $_.Directory.Name, $_.Name }
```

<sup>Note that the brackets around the Get-ChildItem cmdlet are needed to make sure it does not 'pick up' any file you have renamed earlier in the pipe</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tree
.
└── foo
    ├── bar
    │   ├── baz
    │   │   └── file
    │   └── file
    └── file

3 directories, 3 files
$ find . -type f -exec sh -c 'f=${1//\//_}; mv $1 ${1%/*}/${f:2}' _ {} \;
$ tree
.
└── foo
    ├── bar
    │   ├── baz
    │   │   └── foo_bar_baz_file
    │   └── foo_bar_file
    └── foo_file

3 directories, 3 files
```

Comment: I always recommend using `mv -i` or `mv -n` for bulk move/rename operations, to avoid deleting files if there's any sort of naming conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Foreach {
  $Parent = Split-Path "$_.Fullname" -Parent
  $Name = "$($Parent)" + "_" + "$_.Name"
  Renmae-Item -Path "$_.Fullname" -Newname "$Name"
}
```